# Object-oriented python

Tags: python

I have a simple example of class in python:

```
class song:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print x

bang=song(['Our whole universe was in a hot dense state,Then nearly fourteen billion years ago expansion started, wait...'])
```

This works. 
But in another book the word "object" is used when creating a new class:

```
class song(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        print x

bang=song(['Our whole universe was in a hot dense state,Then nearly fourteen billion years ago expansion started, wait...'])
```

This works too. Plus if object is substituted with, for example, x:

```
class song(x):
    def __init__(self,x):
        print x

smile=song(['Our whole universe was in a hot dense state,Then nearly fourteen billion years ago expansion started, wait...'])
```

It doesn't work (`NameError: name x is not defined`).
What's so special about `object`, as far as I know it isn't even a reserved word, isn't it? And why the code with it works, while with `x` - doesn't?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Inheritance in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) and then at [old vs new style classes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass)

Comment: `NameError` usually refers to an attempted reference to something that does not exist. Just for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because `x` is being treated as a constructor class. This means, basically, that in order for your code to work, `x` would already be defined as a `class`.

When you use `object` to create a class, you are using a template class that is empty to make a new type of class. A similar thing happens with using `int` or `dict`. The new class inherits the properties of the type.

Since the class `x` is not defined, the new class cannot use `x` as the constructor. Therefore, that error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Because `object` is the base object that you are inheriting from. `x` does not exist as an object and therefore cannot be inherited from

You could do:

```
class x(object):
    def __init__(self, item)
        self.item = item


class song(x):
    def print(self):
         print(self.item)


bang=song(['a bunch of text']) #why is this a list?

bang.print()
```

And there you have it `inheritance` - so many x's make this confusing

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should get acquainted with [inheritance](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/)

As shown in other answers it is possible to state `class song(x):`, if x is a class on its own. By doing this the `song`class will inherit the methods from the base class x.

Now, the reason for a class declaration to inherit from object dates back to python2.2. These type of class declarations are called : `New style classes`.

They have a different object model to classic objects and have a set of properties and features that are not present in classic objects. Some examples of this are the @property keyword, the super() method. More details about their difference can be found [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass), but it's also widely discussed on Stack Overflow: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python).

It is advised to use these `new style classes` and so to let your base classes inherit from the `object` class.